# IntelliJ Idea doesn't see dependency, which was added by Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have such *build.gradle* file:

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

jar {
    baseName = 'test'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

ext{
    //versions of dependencies
    springVersion = '5.0.4.RELEASE'
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    springJPAVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    javaxVersion = '1.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${springJPAVersion}"
    implementation "javax.persistence:persistence-api:${javaxVersion}"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

And build task is executed successfully:

```
21:56:37: Executing external task 'build'...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test NO-SOURCE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
21:56:37: External task execution finished 'build'.
```

And in *C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.persistence\persistence-api\1.0.2\8...a* Gradle downloaded archive *persistence-api-1.0.2.jar*, which contains *javax\persistence\Entity.class*.

But when I'm trying to add line:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

in any class, IntelliJ Idea underlines persistence with red. Why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Add the library to your module's dependencies in Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S).

Comment: @Bucket, but when I select adding "Module Dependencie" to module, I get the following message: "Found no modules to depend on"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last I've pushed "Refresh all Gradle project" in *Gradle projects* window:

[image]

and all dependencies suddenly appeared in module's dependencies in Project Structure. And after that my problem was fixed.